# Buying Error - Merchant is not a business account

Tags: encryption, paypal, merchant-account

I have a marketplace where "vendors" can sell items, though whenever a vendor puts up an item and the buyer tries to buy it, they receive the following error when getting redirected:

*The merchant is not a business or premier PayPal account. This feature is only enabled for a business or a premier PayPal account holder.*

I am also using encrypted Payments.
I mean, when I set it to my email it works, but when it is not set to mine it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are changing Business email then you have to re-generate public, private keys for encrypted payments.

Keys should be generated from same business account on which you are sending money.